# Problem with libhdf5 dependency

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I had an issue updating my Fuerte packages. When I ran

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I received the error

```
"E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

for 12 packages.

After digging into the issue, I found that **ros-fuerte-perception-pcl requires libhdf5-serial-dev**. However, I had installed Paraview (which has a PCL viewer plugin) and **paraview requires libhdf5-openmpi-dev**. It appears these two packages are mutually exclusive.

Because I haven't been using Paraview lately, I decided to uninstall it so I could update my ROS Fuerte install. However, since it was coexisting peacefully before I feel something must have changed.

During the uninstall of Paraview and update of perception-pcl, I noticed that **libnetcdf6 can use either libhdf5-serial or -openmpi**

```
$ apt-cache depends libnetcdf6 
libnetcdf6
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libgfortran3
 |Depends: libhdf5-serial-1.8.4
  Depends: <libhdf5-1.8.4>
    libhdf5-lam-1.8.4
    libhdf5-mpich-1.8.4
    libhdf5-openmpi-1.8.4
    libhdf5-serial-1.8.4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Conflicts: libnetcdf6:i386
```

**Could perception-pcl be modified to accept either also?** This would allow Paraview installation again.

Yes, I'm also going to query the Ubuntu package maintainers about doing the same with Paraview.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67316/problem-with-libhdf5-dependency/) by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2013-07-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem can be overcome by a little hack. Because libhdf5-serial package contains all the files paraview needs, it is just sufficient to tell apt-get that the package libhdf5-openmpi has already been installed. You can download a "fake" package from https://app.box.com/s/1atz60r66dwke4xmsx01 .

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2013-10-14**:
If you don't trust that file, you can create your own onw using the tutorial at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726317 (just the main-package part, without coping with the .conf file).

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2013-10-14**:
To install the downloaded .deb file just double-click it and install it. If that doesn't work for you, you can always do `sudo dpkg -i name_of_file.deb` .